# Why regular oracle table support DML statements,but not the same for External table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, external-tables

This is known to us that all *DML* statement has been supported by **Oracle Regular Table** but not the same for **External Table**? I tried below :

```
SQL> INSERT INTO  xtern_empl_rpt VALUES ('70','Rakshit','Nantu','4587966214','na
tu.rakshit@ge.com','55');
INSERT INTO  xtern_empl_rpt VALUES ('70','Rakshit','Nantu','4587966214','natu.ra
kshit@ge.com','55')
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30657: operation not supported on external organized table


SQL> update xtern_empl_rpt set FIRST_NAME='Arup' where SSN='896743856';
update xtern_empl_rpt set FIRST_NAME='Arup' where SSN='896743856'
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30657: operation not supported on external organized table


SQL>
```

So it seems **External table** not support this. But my question is - what the logical reason behind this design?

Answer (score 3):

There is no mechanism in Oracle for locking rows in external tables, none of the concurrency controls which we get with regular heap tables.  So updating is not allowed.

External tables created with the Oracle Loader driver are read only; the Datapump driver allows us to write to external table files but only in an CTAS mode.

The problem is that eternal tables are basically windows on OS files, without the layer of abstraction and control that internal tables offer.  Basically, there is no way for the database to lock a record in an OS file, because the notion of a "record" is a databse thang, not an OS file thang.

Comment: Could you explain this with a code if possible - `Datapump driver allows us to write to external table files but only in an CTAS mode.` ?

Comment: There is an entire chapter on the Datapump diver for External Tables in the Utilities Guide" http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_dp_driver.htm#i1006773  The key thing is, it doesn't extend to UPDATE.

Comment: so we can say it  like `as per the design`, although i was looking for some other kind of answers,but seems here it will not come. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

External tables are designed for only one thing: data loading and unloading. They are simply not meant to be used with normal DML, and they're not really meant for normal `select`s either - that works, but if you need to do a lot of selections on an external table, you're "doing it wrong": load the data into proper tables, calculate statistics & add indexes as necessary.

Having external tables behave like normal tables would need that all the transactional machinery be implemented for them, which is very complex, and not worth it since that's not what they are meant for.

If you need normal tables and want to transplant them from one Oracle database to another, you should evaluate using [transportable tablespaces](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces013.htm) too.

Answer (score 0):

Limitations of external table are an obvious consequence of their being read-only; they are an adapter to involve in SQL queries either arbitrary record-organized files (ORACLE_LOADER type) or exported copies of tables in another database (ORACLE_DATAPUMP type).

As already mentioned, external tables are only good for full table scan queries; if one needs to use indexes in heavy duty queries or to modify foreign data sets that have been imported from files, regular tables can be populated using the SQL Loader tool.